# UILocalizedIndexedCollation not showing chinese characters

Tags: objective-c, ios, localization

In my iphone application iam using English, Spanish, Russian and Chinese localizations. The localizations works fine for all localized strings. But *UILocalizedIndexedCollation* doesnt work for chinese language. The table indices are showing correctly when i change device language to English, Spanish and Russian. But when i set device language as Chinese, iam geting the table indices in English, at the same time localized string are chinese itself.

```
[[UILocalizedIndexedCollation currentCollation] sectionIndexTitles]
```

The above code returns an array of english alphabets for Chinese localization, while it returns correct character array for other three languages (English, Spanish and Russian).

Iam using the following .lproj files for localization

1. English - en.lproj
2. Spanish - es.lproj
3. Russian - ru.lproj
4. Chinese - zh_Hans.lproj

Can anyone help me finding the problem.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

By Apple http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#qa/qa1739/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40011151

> The localization data that UILocalizedIndexedCollation uses at
>   run-time will be based on the localization that your application
>   bundle is using. If your application only supports English, and the
>   device is set to use Traditional Chinese, UILocalizedIndexedCollation
>   will only show English section titles and sort rows into the "A"
>   through "Z" and "#" sections, even though UILocalizedIndexedCollation
>   is capable of providing Traditional Chinese section titles and sorting
>   row data into these sections.
>
> To address this, your application bundle must properly declare support
>   for the languages you want UILocalizedIndexedCollation to support. You
>   can add localizations to your application bundle either by adding the
>   appropriate .lproj folders, or by specifying supported localizations
>   in your CFBundleLocalizations key in your application's info.plist
>   file. Note that the former approach is preferred, as it easier to
>   maintain if localized resources need to be added to your application
>   in the future

Comment: Not sure if you helped the asker or not, but the link to the Apple docs were exactly the info I was looking for, thanks.